# How to import JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

```
package main;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main extends JPanel{

    public Main() {
        add(new Panel());
        setName("NGame");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

The `import javax.swing.JFrame;` line isn't recognized as a class by eclipse and will not import. The two set methods are not recognised as the JFrame will not import. I have the latest JDK and have checked that the JFrame class is existant with the <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> command. What is happening?

Comment: Why don't you try to use a regular editor.

Comment: @yannis What do you mean by "regular editor"?

Comment: `Notepad++`,`SublimeText`,even nano or vi. And JDK tools `javac` and `java`. It's good to avoid an IDE such as `eclipse` when you start a language.

Comment: Being much more experienced now in languages and cs in general, I would have to disagree with you. I would argue that IDEs like Eclipse are effective for learning language syntax/libraries. @giannischristofakis

Comment: Nevertheless, that's just my opinion. The would be times in your programming career that you will need to develop on a dev server without any IDE or UI. Also I've met a lot of budding developers that they don't know how to build/deploy or even compile a source file without an IDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make `Main` extend `JFrame`, not `JPanel`. Try something like this:

```
package main;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Main extends JFrame {

    public Main() {
       add(new JPanel());
       //...other code
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Several things...

1. You are extending from `JPanel`, but not importing it.
2. You are importing `JFrame`, but not actually using it.
3. `setDefaultCloseOperation` is not a valid method for `JPanel`
4. `EXIT_ON_CLOSE` is an unknown variable as it's not declared  within `JPanel` or any of it's parent classes...
5. You are mixing heavy and light weight components (`Panel` is a heavy weight component and `JPanel` is a light weight component, these components tend not to mix well)

Instead, try extending from `JFrame` instead...

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Main extends JFrame {

    public Main() {
        add(new JPanel());
        setName("NGame");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Now, having said that.  It's generally not necessary to extend from `JFrame` as you rarely add any new functionality to it.

Instead, you should create an instance of `JFrame` and add your components to it, for example...

```
package main;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Panel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new MainPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class MainPane extends JPanel {
        public MainPane() {
            add(new Panel());
            setName("NGame");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: +1 OK I don't think anyone can compete this. Could you point me the use of `setName`?

Comment: @yannishristofakis The "main" reason I see for `setName` is for GUI form designers.  It might also be useful if you have multiple instance of the same type of object that you want to identify, but don't have a reference to the initial variables.  And yes, there are plenty of people who compete with me and keep me focused on being my best and maintain a high standard. They routinely kick my in the back side if I slip ... and I appreciate when they done ;)

Answer (score 1):

Right click on src, then build path, libraries, and remove the JRE System Library, add libraries and add it again. This helped it for me at least =)

Answer (score 0):

That's because *JPanel* doesn't have those methods. *setName* <del>doesn't even exists.</del> exists, but I don't think it's what you meant to do.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Main extends JFrame {

    public Main() {
        //instead of setName()
        setTitle("NGame");
        add(new Panel());
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //setVisible(true);
        //pack();
        //etc etc
    }
}
```

Comment: *"setName doesn't even exists"* - Ah, yeah it does...[`Component#setName`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setName(java.lang.String))

Comment: @MadProgrammer I know,I don't think he meant to use it in this way. Don't forget he is a beginner.